# Sharing a file with Android Intent: File extension is removed

Tags: java, android, file, audio, sharing

I'm using the following code to share an audio file with Android Studio 3.3.2 and Java. The file is extracted from the /raw/ folder.

```
public void funktionTeilen(String file) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + file);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/mpeg3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Audio teilen"));
}
```

In principle the sharing works fine, but the file is sent without a file extension, which of course makes it unreadable by most apps. If I add the file extension manually (for example after downloading it from the e-mail client), the MP3 works fine.

"file" is fed in by another function and corresponds to the file name from the raw folder. It is also found basically, otherwise the sharing process would not work at all.

So, how can I share a file with retention of the file extension? Thanks for your help!

**Update #1**

```
public void funktionTeilen(String Datei) {


    try {
        File tmpFile = new File(this.getCacheDir() + "/tmpfile.mp3");
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.meise1);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile, true);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;

        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }

        // Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getPackageName(), tmpFile);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tmpFile);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/*");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Audio teilen"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the solution!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void funktionTeilen(String Datei) {

    try {
        File tmpFile = new File(this.getCacheDir() + "/tmpfile.mp3");
        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.meise1);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile, false);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;

        try {
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            /* if (tmpFile.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } */
        }

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, tmpFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/mpeg3");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Audio teilen"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
        <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>

    </provider>

</application>
```

**file_provider_paths.xml**

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
    <files-path name="files" path="/" />
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using the following code to share an audio file with Android Studio 3.3.2 and Java

You are sharing a resource. That is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device.

> In principle the sharing works fine, but the file is sent without a file extension, which of course makes it unreadable by most apps.

In Android, resources do not have file extensions when we work with them using the Android SDK.

> So, how can I share a file with retention of the file extension?

If you share an actual *file*, using `FileProvider`, it will have a file extension. So, copy the bytes corresponding to your resource to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then set up `FileProvider` and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to use with `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, I'm very new to Android and Java. So it's not always that easy to understand. Could you take a look at my updated code? Unfortunately, the file is apparently not transferred. However, an exception is thrown neither.

Comment: @CorAngar: `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+, as it will trigger an exception. Use `FileProvider` as I noted (and as you have commented out). Also, please use the real MIME type. *You* are the one sharing the content, so *you* need to know what MIME type it is and use it. Wildcards are OK when the other party is the one with the content (e.g., `<intent-filter>`, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`).

Comment: Thanks! The file is transferred correctly from the resource and everything seems to be working fine, except for the commented out  `Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getPackageName(), tmpFile);` I also tried `tmpFile.getAbsolutePath();` which does not work either. It causes a Java.lang.NullPointerException.
Do you have any further suggestions? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @CorAngar: "except for the commented out" -- why did you comment it out? What is the specific problem that you are encountering?

Comment: I commented it out, because it does not work unfortunately. `Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getPackageName(), tmpFile);` results in a `Java.lang.NullPointerException` which probably means, that the file can not be found with this code. Maybe it has something to do with "this" or "this.getPackageName()"?
 `if (tmpFile.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }`
throws a valid path. The file exists and is transferred correctly, which the .length(); shows.

Comment: @CorAngar: Edit your question and show the complete stack trace for the error, along with your `FileProvider` metadata XML.

Comment: Thanks for your help @CommonsWare. I did not even consider creating the metadata for the `FileProvider`. I surely need more basic knowledge in Android and Java. Anyway, I posted the solution for everyone.